# How do I use an extracted string to call an xts data object?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I want to use a string of stock symbols and loop through it pulling pairs into a block of code for analysis. I can get the loop to pull in the data but then I want to assign the data to a generic data element so I can just run it through my code. Can't get hold of the *xts* object from the list programmatically and get it to execute - just returns the value.

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

asset1 = "ADBE"
asset2 = "VGT"

assets <- c(asset1, asset2)
assets       # This returns [1] "ADBE "VGT"

getSymbols(assets[1]) # All good so far this returns an xts object [1:3247] [1:6] called ADBE
```

Manually if I enter:

```
df01 = ADBE # This makes df01 the same as the data values for ADBE.
df01 <- assets[1] # makes df01 a character string equal to "ADBE"
```

**Question:**

How do I make the **df01 = ADBE** piece happen programmatically using the values in assets. When I use assets[1] it fails and as I don't want to type the stock codes every time but assign it and as I loop through a list of assets(n) using generic code.

I realise this is probably a simple dumb question but its got me stumped and cannot find a solution on-line.

Comment: When I tried this myResult held a list of the symbols.  It did not hold the data. I am trying to use the item in the names list to e.g. ADBE to call the data created by getSymbols which has the same name as the item in the list.  When I do df01 <- assets[1] i get the symbol code used by getSymbols not the data created by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the results in one list, by default *getSymbols* assigns every asset into the environment, we can change this by using `auto.assign = FALSE`, example:

```
myResult <- lapply(assets, getSymbols, auto.assign = FALSE)
myResult <- setNames(myResult, assets)

# access using names
myResult$ADBE
#            ADBE.Open ADBE.High ADBE.Low ADBE.Close ADBE.Volume ADBE.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     40.72     41.32    38.89      39.92     7126000         39.92
# ...

# or using a variable
assets[ 1 ]
# [1] "ADBE"
myResult[[ assets[ 1 ] ]]
#           ADBE.Open ADBE.High ADBE.Low ADBE.Close ADBE.Volume ADBE.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     40.72     41.32    38.89      39.92     7126000         39.92
# ...
```

If we do not wish to keep them in a list, then maybe use `get`:

```
getSymbols(assets)
df01 <- get(assets[ 1 ])
df01
#            ADBE.Open ADBE.High ADBE.Low ADBE.Close ADBE.Volume ADBE.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     40.72     41.32    38.89      39.92     7126000         39.92
# ...
```